# Javascript "for" syntax

Tags: javascript

So in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833756/what-was-used-to-compress-this-code) I asked about how some Javascript was compressed. The question was answered yet the following snippet confuses me so much that I had to ask another question. Here it is:

```
for (Y = 0; $ = 'zxqj`_^ZWVUQONMKJIHGCA@8$  ' [Y++];) 
     with(_.split($)) _ = join(pop());
eval(_)
```

Where does this syntax come from? I kind of understand what the third for operation is (`[Y++]`), but why is it in brackets and why isn't there any semicolon before it? Also, at line 2: it looks to me like `_` is a variable being declared, but what kind of variable type is `with(_.split($))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any `for` command can be broken down. Start with the "classic" loop:

```
for( i=0; i<end; i++)
```

This translates to:

- Set `i=0`
- Repeat the following as long as `i<end`:

  - Run the code in the block
  - Increment `i`

So, applying the same to your code:

- Set `Y=0`
- As long as the character in position Y of the string exists (ie. Y is not past the length of the string), assign that character to `$` and then increment Y, then:

  - Run the code in the block
  - Do nothing (there is nothing after the second semicolon)

It's ugly as hell, but it still makes sense if you break it down.

Comment: So the `[Y++]` is a kind of regular expression?

Comment: No, it's accessing a string as an array of characters. Many languages support this, not just JavaScript.

Comment: Ohhhhhh, I see. I would never have thought of that with the space in between!